# how to use npm install's --force flag during Visual Studio publish process?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm

I have an Angular project in Visual Studio, along with a publish profile to publish to IIS. I've been successfully using this process in this project for some time now, but suddenly today it wants to give me dependency issues during publish. However, there are no such dependency issues when simply running from source (IIS Express).

Here is some of the output during publishing:

```
MYPROJECT -> C:\Users\ME\Documents\Repositories4\MYPROJECT\bin\Release\net5.0\MYPROJECT.Views.dll
npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ng-connection-service@1.0.4
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@8.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"8.2.12" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from ng-connection-service@1.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/ng-connection-service
npm ERR!   ng-connection-service@"^1.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@6.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from ng-connection-service@1.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/ng-connection-service
npm ERR!     ng-connection-service@"^1.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I have repeatedly tried uninstalling/reinstalling, deleting `node_modules` folder and reinstalling, etc.

Is it possible to modify Visual Studio's publish commands to include `--force` during `npm install`? (If so, where would I do that?) Would that *maybe* solve the issue? Or do you have any other ideas how to get this to publish? I don't think the actual dependency issue is an issue, seeing as how I am able to run from source just fine, so I feel like if I could just tell Visual Studio to force it anyway, then that would probably work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**Update 5/3/2023**
I ended up giving up on Visual Studio's Angular project template. Now I just use Angular's default project and just open the `ClientApp` folder in Visual Studio for development, and use `ng serve` to serve it up. I have had ZERO package dependency issues since going this route. VS just doesn't have a great starting point with their template imho.

---

Apparently the publish process has these commands defined in the `.csproj` file:

```
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

I updated that to use the `--force` flag during `npm install`.

It fixed a couple things but still having issues publishing, despite being able to run from source, and despite my coworker being able to check out the same repo and publish it just fine. Something is wonky with my `npm` packages or maybe `typescript`, IDK. I'll update this answer if/when I figure it out. Until then, please let me know if any of you have any ideas.